# Non existence of an unbiased estimator

Tags: statistics

How can you show that $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}\sim B(1,p)$ independent and $Y_{1},\ldots Y_{n}\sim B(1,q)$ for $p,q \in (0,1)$ and $X_{1},\ldots X_{n},Y_{1}\ldots,Y_{n}$ independent, there exsits no unbiased estimator for $\gamma:=p/q$. I always concerned unbiasedness with respect to one law. But here we have random variables on two laws.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that an unbiased estimator of $\gamma(p,q)$ is a function $c:\{0,1\}^{2n}\to\mathbb R$ such that, for every $(p,q)$, $$E_{p,q}(c(X_1,\ldots,X_n,Y_1,\ldots,Y_n))=\gamma(p,q),$$ that is, $$\sum_{x,y}{n\choose|x|}p^{|x|}(1-p)^{n-|x|}{n\choose|y|}q^{|y|}(1-q)^{n-|y|}c(x,y)=\gamma(p,q),$$ where the sum on the LHS is over every $x$ and $y$ in $\{0,1\}^n$ and where $|x|=x_1+\cdots+x_n$ for every $x=(x_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ in  $\{0,1\}^n$.

The LHS is a polynomial function of $(p,q)$ hence it cannot coincide with the rational function $\gamma:(p,q)\mapsto p/q$ for every $(p,q)$ in $(0,1)^2$, QED.

Another, easier, argument is that $\gamma(p,q)$ is unbounded when $q\to0$ and $p$ is fixed, while the LHS is uniformly at most $K(c)=\sup\{c(x,y)\mid x\in\{0,1\}^n,y\in\{0,1\}^n\}$, hence these cannot coincide for every $(p,q)$.